# Jump to next line in single print function

Tags: python-3.x

The title may not be perfect.
I am trying to create an IP lookup/tracker program using an api in python3 everything seems good but I don't like how the output is printed in the terminal. And btw I am still new to python.

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from urllib.request import urlopen
content = urlopen("http://api.hackertarget.com/geoip/?q=139.59.19.197")
print(content.read())
```

The output I get:

```
b'IP Address: 139.59.19.197\nCountry: IN\nState: Karnataka\nCity: Bangalore\nLatitude: 12.983300\nLongitude: 77.583298'
```

The output I want:

```
IP Address: 139.59.19.197
Country: IN
State: Karnataka
City: Bangalore
Latitude: 12.983300
Longitude: 77.583298
```

Is there any way I can fix this please?

Comment: `print(content.read().decode())`?

Comment: yeah of course! thanks mate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `urllib` read method gives you a raw string of bytes, not text. Python represents that with escaping any character not in the 32-127 range.

All you need is to decode the data you receive into proper text before printing.

Of course, the "easy" way is to naively pick up an encoding such as  "utf-8" and use that. However, the HTTP data you retrieve will have, at some point, the proper encoding to use - either on its headers, or as inside a meta `html` tag.

That is why we usually make use of the external `requests` library for this kind of thing.

In this case, you seem to be consuming a web-service that only have ASCII characters anyway. So you can use "latin1" and just risk having any mojibake:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from urllib.request import urlopen
content = urlopen("http://api.hackertarget.com/geoip/?q=139.59.19.197")
data = content.read().decode("latin1")
print(data)
```

When you have 5 minutes to spare, please take a read at this:
https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/ - it is from 2003, but not less important today.

Comment: Are you sure `encode` is what is needed for a byte string?

Comment: sorry. the other way around. fixed now